# ClickOnce deployment error due to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0 Version9.0.0.0 missing from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I am developing a C# application in VS 2010 that is to be deployed via ClickOnce. However when I try to deploy the application on a client machine I get the following error:

*Unable to install or run the application. The application requires the assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0 Version 9.0.0.0 to be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.*

I have tried to include the missing assembly into the application files under Project Properties->Publish tab, but the error remains the same. Next I tried to add *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0* to the project's references, but I cannot find it in the reference list.

Does anyone have any tips or solutions to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something is pretty borked if this is not meant to be a Visual Studio add-in.  Document the non-standard references in the References node.

Comment: What kind of application is it? Is it VSTO? Win Forms? WPF? Console Application?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. In Solution Explorer, right click the project name and select properties.
2. Go to the References tab.
3. Click the Unused References button.
4. Save and Publish.

Answer (score 0):

Vron's answer is correct, it is a good idea to remove references to unused assemblies. I think if you understand why its happening then you know how to fix it. VS doesn't think you need the assembly when you publish your program because you haven't used  it (as far as it can tell) but you have added it to your reference list. So it doesn't package it.

You either need to remove it from your reference list, or you need to ensure it is included in your project. To do this, show hidden, right click on the reference that is missing, click properties, and set "Copy Local" to true. Worked for me and MySQL.